# Yaml file rewrite outputing "type mismatch"

Tags: jenkins, groovy, yaml, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to write to a yaml file, specifically overwrite, in a declarative pipeline in groovy.

```
transfers:
- name: xyz
  cloud: aws
  subheading:
    impact: Low
    reason: ---

  artifacts:
  - name: name1
    type: type1
    source:
      hash: a1b2C3dd4    ---> VALUE TO OVERWRITE
```

```
HASH = sh(returnStdout:true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
data.transfers['artifacts'].source['hash'] = HASH
writeYaml file: filename, data: data, overwrite = true
```

However there is a type mismatch when doing the second line of the code , and it looks like it's because data.transfers['artifacts'].source['hash'] is of type arraylist and I am trying to set it = to HASH which is of type string. I know that to solve this I can just convert the HASH to arrayList, but I don't understand why data.transfers['artifacts'].source['hash'] = HASH doesn't overwrite the value inside the array? Is there anyway to avoid converting the HASH to array list?

Comment: `why data.transfers['artifacts'].source['hash'] = HASH doesn't overwrite the value inside the array?` where do you see an array? could you please show the actual result and expected result?

Comment: The way I know it’s an array is I did an echo “data type: “ + (data.transfers['artifacts'].source['hash']).getClass() and echo "type HASH: " + HASH.getClass(). First one gave output of ArrayList and the second one gave output of string.

Comment: The actual result is an error: "argument type mismatch". The expected result is having the hash inside the yaml file being replaced with the output of HASH = sh(returnStdout:true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim().

Comment: I don't know Groovy but `data.transfers` is a sequence in your YAML and you definitely can't just access `['artifacts']` in there without giving an index first. Same with the `artifacts` value then, that's also a sequence and you need another index.

Comment: Flyx you were right with the index, the solution to read and write the correct string ended up being datas.transfers[0].artifacts[0].source.hash